# Rotate Label not working in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

`RotateLabel->False` is not working for me in ListPlot. I'm using Mathematica 13.1 for Mac OS X Arm (64-bit). For example, this produces the error for me

```
ListPlot[Table[Sin[t], {t, 0, 10, 1}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, RotateLabel -> False]
```

The y axis label remains rotated in the output.

Comment: If I run your code as it is, and then the same code with `RotateLabel -> True`, then I get two different orientations for the label "y". Are you saying that both `-> False` and `-> True` give exactly the same result for you, so that `RotateLabel` has no effect at all? I use Version 12.3.

Comment: MMA version 13.1 I can reproduce this bug.